# Is WebRTC Multicast possible in Local Network?

Tags: networking, routes, webrtc, p2p, multicast

I have a surveillance Camera and i want to stream the live feed to multiple clients in the same network using WebRTC. To save compute resource and bandwidth requirement i want to do multicasting on WebRTC feed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC doesn't support multicast. You might want to look into tools like webtorrent.

Comment: WebRTC runs over UDP. Multicast can be done over UDP. So is the issue with the WebRTC stack? Is there any way of integrating IGMP with webrtc stack?

Comment: webrtc uses SRTP encryption based on DTLS-SRTP. You can't use multicast with that.

Comment: Can SRTP encryption be deactivated so multicast with udp can work?